# Threejs million faces rendering performace collada files

Tags: performance, import, three.js, collada

I have two .dae files, one has 1 million faces and the second one has 20 millions faces.
I imported them using ColladaLoader.
The problem is that the 20 millions faces run at 30fps and the 1 million faces run at 2fps.
How is that? How can i fix that?

Comment: It's not only the number of faces that determines performace. Can you maybe provide a code-sample? Other factors could be: number of meshes, number and type of materials, number of faces actually rendered, and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You have to check how many meshes are there in those models. Performance largely depends on the number of draw calls (meshes) in a model since more draw calls means more data passing to GPU.

For an example, I had a mesh with 3.5 million faces and it had more than 1000 meshes. I got 20 fps for that. But when i merged all the meshes to a single mesh, i got 60 fps.

The solution of this problem is to merge the geometries of the meshes to a single one and build a single mesh using that geometries. For `BufferGeometry`, you can merge all the vertex array, color array and normal array. For merging index array, you have to add the base vertex for each index value.